# Javascript Sliding puzzle not working correctly

Tags: javascript

So I am attempting to make a slider puzzle. I am able to randomize the table and make the proper swaps if I was able to swap the pictures. I cannot for the life of me figure out why I can't swap these pictures and I dont know what to do. I've been stumped for a while and have tried different methods.

How the puzzle should operate is that when any tile near the blank tile (will be a black picture) is clicked, as long as they are adjacent to the blank tile, they will swap places.

So only those tiles can swap and no others. Eventually the puzzle will be solved.

```
<html>

<script>

picArray = [
    "faceassingment6_01.png",
    "faceassingment6_02.png",
    "faceassingment6_03.png",
    "faceassingment6_04.png",
    "faceassingment6_05.png",
    "faceassingment6_06.png",
    "faceassingment6_07.png",
    "faceassingment6_08.png",
    "backtile.png"
]
sramArray = []
function scramblePic()
{
    var seven = 7
        for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        {
            r = Math.floor(Math.random() * picArray.length)
            x = picArray[r]

            sramArray.push(x)
            picArray.splice(r , 1)

            document.getElementById(i).src = sramArray[i]
        }
}

function moveTile(x)
{
    blankVal = document.getElementById("8").src
    var blankCount = 0;
    var cols = 3

    for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
            if (sramArray[i] == "backtile.png")
            {
                temp = sramArray[i]
                sramArray[i] = sramArray[blankCount]
                sramArray[blankCount] = temp
                break;

            }
            else
            {
                blankCount++
            }
    }

    if ((((x == blankCount - 1) || (x == blankCount + 1)) && ((Math.floor(x/cols)) == (Math.floor(blankCount/cols)))) || (x == blankCount + cols) || (x == blankCount - cols))
  {
                temp = document.images[x].src
                document.images[x].src = sramArray[blankCount]
                // = temp

    }
}

</script>
<head>
    <title> test </title>

</head>
    <body bgcolor="gray" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload = "scramblePic()">

            <table id="Table_01" width="600" height="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align = "center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="faceassingment6_01.png" width="200" height="200" alt="" id = "0" onclick = "moveTile(0)"></td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="faceassingment6_02.png" width="200" height="200" alt="" id = "1" onclick = "moveTile(1)"></td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="faceassingment6_03.png" width="200" height="200" alt="" id = "2" onclick = "moveTile(2)"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="faceassingment6_04.png" width="200" height="200" alt="" id = "3" onclick = "moveTile(3)"></td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="faceassingment6_05.png" width="200" height="200" alt="" id = "4" onclick = "moveTile(4)"></td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="faceassingment6_06.png" width="200" height="200" alt="" id = "5" onclick = "moveTile(5)"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="faceassingment6_07.png" width="200" height="200" alt="" id = "6" onclick = "moveTile(6)"></td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="faceassingment6_08.png" width="200" height="200" alt="" id = "7" onclick = "moveTile(7)"></td>
                    <td>
            <img src = "backtile.png" width = "200" height = "200" alt = "" id = "8" onclick = "moveTile(8)" >
          </td>
                </tr>
            </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote at least explain why

Comment: Possible for you to create a working example of what you currently have please? I have changed the images in the attempt to understand your question more but it hasn't made anything any more clear. Maybe create  a [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/) - Here is what I have attempted to work with [**JsFiddle Attempt**](https://jsfiddle.net/z8c4vLLs/)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why, but jsfiddle doesn't seem to work with my function calls. It works in my standard notepad but not in there. I compensated for the values and such. I updated the description in hopes to make it more clear what I am attempting to do

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem. It was simply the way I was trying to find the blank picture as well as how I was swapping them. Here is the correct function code:

```
function moveTile(x)
{
    var blankCount = 0;
    var cols = 3
    var count = 0

    while (sramArray[count] != "backtile.png")
    {
        ++blankCount
        ++count
    }

    if ((((x == blankCount - 1) || (x == blankCount + 1)) && ((Math.floor(x/cols)) == (Math.floor(blankCount/cols)))) || (x == blankCount + cols) || (x == blankCount - cols))
  {
            temp = document.images[x].src
            document.images[x].src = document.images[blankCount].src
            document.images[blankCount].src = temp

            holdVal = sramArray[x]
        sramArray[x] = sramArray[blankCount]
        sramArray[blankCount] = holdVal

            blankCount = 0
            count = 0

            checkPuzzle()
    }
}
```